# Invalid username and password - ORA-01017 while testing datasource connection in websphere admin console

Tags: oracle11g, websphere

I am trying to test my oracle datasource connection in websphere admin console. Though, I give the correct username and password, I am getting invalid username/password logon denied. I know there are several posts related to this. But, none of them solved my issue. I tried the following,
1. I am able to connect to the same environment in Toad with the same credentials.
2. I tried updating the password in admin console under Security->J2C authentication, still getting the same error.
3. After changing the password in console, restarted the server.
4. this is a standalone application, so there are no nodeagents to be restarted as mentioned in other posts.
5. Some posts online shows that this is a bug with Oracle. Need to connect with Oracle support team and get this fixed. 
I have no clue, how should I proceed with this!! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you said "this is a standalone application", I'm assuming you mean a standalone application server.  1) Are you using an authentication alias, setting userid and password properties on the datasource, or supplying the userid and password in the connection URL?  2) Is your application able to connection to the ora instance using the configured credentials?  3) Are you using just userid and password for authentication or do you have a wallet configured?

Comment: Hi, yes I am using an authentication alias, with userid and password set and not in the URL.Yes I am able to connect to the datasource  with the same credentials via Toad for Oracle. After doing some research online, I tried to syncNode but I got node is not incorporated into the cell error.

Comment: You don't need to do syncNode on a standalone server.  What do you have set in the "Security Settings" section of the datasource you're testing?

Comment: In addition to verifying the settings as I mentioned in previous comment, you should also validate that the password stored in the auth alias is what you intend.  Since the password is obscured in the admin console, you can't directly view the existing value, but if you edit the auth alias and replace the obscured password with the intended value and press Ok, if you are prompted to save the config changes, you know that the previously stored password did not match what you entered.  If on the other hand, you are not prompted to save config, they matched.  I suspect they will not match.

Comment: Did you select this alias as 'Component authentication alias' in the datasource configuration?